# Access forbidden! for virtual host when documentroot is outside of apache default root

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, virtualhost

I have a virtual host:

```
Listen 192.168.0.1:2020
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:2020
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:2020>
   DocumentRoot "D:/docs"
</VirtualHost>
```

no when i try to access virtual host, i get `403` error:

**Access forbidden!**
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

**Edit**
Apache is installed in `D:/apache`
while virtual host is in `D:/docs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with adding

```
<Directory D:/docs>
  Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: @MightyPork try set the folder permission `chmod 775`

Answer (score 1):

403 access forbidden means just that. Check that the apache process has permission to read and traverse the underlying filesystem d:/docs. If it doesn't then make it so.

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this under `DocumentRoot`:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

> ### What is FollowSymLinks?
>
> Symbolic links (also called symlinks or softlinks) most resemble Windows shortcuts. Websites are often set up in a way that they show pictures and other content as being physically located at some other location than they really are.
>
> > *source: http://www.maxi-pedia.com/FollowSymLinks*

Comment: Not completely solved the problem